# MS Studio 2012 - How to make it behave more like Netbeans/Java?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I started yesterday on learning C++ with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. I have a background of 1-2 years with Netbeans and Java, and I use the code completion features a lot.

So I got a few questions here for MS Studio 2012:

- In Netbeans you can alt+I to fix imports, what is Studio counterpart?
- In Netbeans/Java if you type `File file = new File();` and then press alt+I, it will automatically add `import java.io.File;`

I am really stunned by the following thing though in MS Studio 2012, which I would like to solve:

- In the first "Hello World!"-tutorial I have to write to the console using `cout << "Hello World!"`, so I typed that... But it did not give me any option to automatically do `using namespace std;` and/or `#include <iostream>`.

Is there a way to make whole MS Studio 2012 behave as closely as possibly to what I have been used in Netbeans/Java?

Comment: Removing `[java]` and `[netbeans]` as the answer won't have anything to do with those.

Comment: Don't forget that Java is a feature poor language making it easier for a program to understand and instrument the code.

Comment: If you try IntelliJ, you will find you don't need to write half the code you mentioned, even more is automatically filled for you.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am planning on first learning C++ somewhat and then trying to make a simple game with OGRE. I read it requires Visual Studio 2012 for plugins, so I was thinking that Studio 2012 would be the best choice? Or am I wrong in there

Comment: I would expect that Visual Studio is best for windows C++ applications.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, C++ is not Java, and #includes are not imports. The IDE can not know in which headers the classes and functions you want to use are declared/defined. To do that, it would have to parse any header inside the include path. And since per sé *any* file can be used as a header, i.e. can be included, it would have to (try to) parse *any* file in the whole include path.
Again, C++ is not Java, so compared to Java C++ has some strengths and weaknesses. One of the latter is the need to manage your includes manually.

**Update:** As has been noted by Martin Ba, there are tools that can give you assistance on a set of classes, e.g. classes from common libraries like the standard library and the classes defined inside your VS project, but those are third party tools and have to rely on manually managed databases that would need to be extended in order for the feature to work properly in the presence of other libraries.

**tl;dr** you can't get the automatic import for everything in C++

Comment: +1 The power of C++ is that you have more control over almost every aspect of the program. On the downside, the IDE cannot make as many assumptions about how the program should be written.

Comment: @MartinBa: No you *cannot*. You can try, yes, but it's does not have to be even correct. Lots of MSDN symbols are "defined in X, include Y". All right, completion can take this into account but it is not going to work with others code anyway.

Comment: @MartinBa you can get assistance for a known set of classes and functions, yes. However you can't get that automagically for virtually *everything* like in Java, because it requires some kind of database about what is defined where. That database is included in the *.class files in the classpath in Java, but it does not exist in standard C++

Comment: @Roman: You guys are aware that saying "you cannot." And saying "you cannot with 100% accuracy." are quite two different things? The VSX feature *is* useful and works in *many* cases.

Comment: @MartinBa: Yes this saying is to correct your "you can". I am not even mentioning that include order might also be important.

Comment: @MartinBa the OP wants the feature he knows from Java (i.e. automatic import for *all* classes), and that's not possible in C++

Comment: @MartinBa I added and paragraph about the possibility of those thirdparty tools to my answer.

Comment: I would be quite happy with it working for the standard libraries. But I do not want to pay for it basically. What options are there left then?

Comment: I guess then you'll need to **a)** google for a MSVC plugin that knows the current standard classes and their headers (I don't know of any besides VAX), or **b)** develop your own plugin or **c)** be a bit disappointed, deal with it and get used to type the standard headers yourself ;) That's not the biggest annoyance in programming after all.

Comment: @skiwi: Just forget about it. It's a nice feature, but nonessential. When I learned Java, IDEs didn't have this feature either. And it wasn't a problem for Java nor is it one for C++. Not a big deal, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

The refactoring support of VS cannot do this.

However, there is 3rd party Software - Visual Assist X - that has the ability to *try* to include the right header file for a certain symbol. See: [Auto Using and Add Include Directives](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/autoUsing.asp)

The problem for your context would be that it is commercial software that you also can only use with a pay-for non-express version of VS.